# Repeating carousel how to using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel

I saw some carousels on

http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

and i want to know how do they repeat the slides , like if there are 5 slides and when i press next button when i'm on the 5th slide it slides right to 1 without jumping way back left to 1

i want to know how to code it

Please no jquery , JavaScript will be greatly appreciated.

if anyone knows please help me

Comment: i mean NOT like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bew6Z

Comment: They use cloned items for loop.

Answer (score 2):

They are moving the pages around when they get to the ends:

**For the last page, pressing NEXT:**

1. First they move the first page to be placed visually after the last page - just out of the viewport to the right.
2. Then they slide to the right.
3. Lastly the fix the position of all the pages (they move the first page back to the beginning AND moving the viewport to show it at once, without animation).

**For the first page, pressing BACK:**

Same idea in reverse - move the last page to appear first, before the first page, slide back, fix pages and viewport without animation.